# How to call a function from a function?

Tags: function, react-native, scope

I really don't understand 100% well the scope of the variables in react native.

I am calling a function from another component, and within this function there is a call to the component's function, but it seems to be out of the scope of this function:

```
addKeytoUser = (key, userID) => {
    try {
        this.collection(`${usrPostsDB}`).doc(`${key}`)
            .update(`${likesCol}`, firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1))
        .then((result) => {
            this.collection(`${usrLikesCol}`).doc(`${userID}`).add(`${key}`);
             return result;
        }); 
    } catch ({ message }) {
        console.log(message);
    }       
}
```

collection is function of the actual component, the first time that it is called return the right value but when called for second time after a sequential execution inside the (result)=> react returns that this.collection does not exist. 
How can I call the component function from .then()=>

Thank you

Comment: Please add more clarification. Confused between the components,  where the function is or where it is called

Comment: Yes Need more information.

Comment: can you please try `this.addKeytoUser = this.addKeytoUser.bind(this);` in `constructor` function

Comment: @ShaileshRathod that worked well. Add the question and I will accept it as the write answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `collection` function to your `addKeyToUser` function as a prop. It would look something like this:

```
addKeytoUser = (key, userID, collection) => {
    try {
        collection(`${usrPostsDB}`).doc(`${key}`)
          .update(`${likesCol}`, firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1))
          .then((result) => {
            collection(`${usrLikesCol}`).doc(`${userID}`).add(`${key}`);
            return result;
          }); 
    } catch ({ message }) {
        console.log(message);
    }       
}
```

This would also make your code look a bit cleaner and more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind your `addKeytoUser` function, In constructor function like this way `this.addKeytoUser = this.addKeytoUser.bind(this);`